# Ubuntu 16.04 New Install screen icon not functioning properly

Tags: 16.04, icons

New install of Ubuntu 16.04 on an older Dell Optiplex 760.

The issues that needs to be addressed is screen flicker and lack of functionality. After install use CLI to update the system and got this problem

```
Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Fixed that with:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

Followed with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After that was completed the system was rebooted and that is when the issues started.

**The Issue**

I can log in but not all menu icons work. When clicking on the Firefox icon all items on the screen disappear for no more than a flicker but eventually Firefox does start. This routine repeats for for the other 'productivity' type program icons.

The top icon the Ubuntu swirl a click there will cause the screen to flicker but nothing happens. This same thing happens for the setting icon the software icon and so on down the list. But wait there is more when clicking the top right power icon the drop-down menu appears with no screen flicker but when I click on "Shut Down.." the screen flickers goes but the menu to actually shut down the computer does not appear.

But wait there's more. Just hovering the mouse over the menu icon on the left will cause the screen to flicker.

Here screen 'flicker' is that all apps and menu icons, everything on the screen, disappears and just the wallpaper is left on the screen and then screen goes back to normal. There is a pattern to this sequence, first the top menu showing the time and the speaker icon disapears, then the left side icon menu disapears, if there is an app on the fore-front it shifts up and left to fill the space from the recently disappeared top and left menu icons before is disappears showing just the wallpaper.

Any help on addressing this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: It's more like a unfinished upgrade and thus incomplete installation interrupted by some reason, leaving problematic configurations in the desktop session. You may do `apt clean && apt update && apt upgrade` again. Then open the terminal, mv `.confg` and `.cache` away, and relogin to see if there are changes.

Comment: Nah, nothing to do with an incomplete upgrade. After a little more searching ran across a bug report. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1735594, that described my situation. I took the advice of comment #39 but I will re-install Ubuntu this afternoon and follow the fixes down around comment #50.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to have something to do with the video drivers per this bug report

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1735594

The solution offered in comment #39 worked. Upon reading the complete bug report I will reinstall Ubuntu and follow the remedy that is suggested in comment #69 and forward. #39 seems to be the fix to see if it works while #69 seem to be the more permanent solution.

I will do a re-install in the near future and report back my results.